# SpiderMonkey 1.8.5 JS::CallArgsFromVp

Tags: javascript

When I'm working with Native calls at JavaScript engine SpiderMonkey 1.8.5 I've found in documentation such example:

```
static bool
 Func(JSContext* cx, unsigned argc, JS::Value* vp)
 {
    JS::CallArgs args = JS::CallArgsFromVp(argc, vp);
 }
```

but it from SpiderMonkey 17. In SP 1.8.5 I have `CallArgs`, but have no `CallArgsFromVp()`, and it is not clear how to convert `JS::Value*` to `JS::CallArgs`.

Is there some analogue \ prototype for `CallArgsFromVp` in SP 1.8.5?

How to use such Native logic with SP 1.8.5?

Answer (score 0):

In SP 1.8.5 `JS_CALLEE`, `JS_THIS` macros must be used instead.

In my case it looks like:

```
static bool
 Func(JSContext* cx, unsigned argc, jsval *vp)
 {
    JSObject *obj = JS_THIS_OBJECT(cx, vp);
 }
```

Who is awesome? I'm awesome!